# How to configure https in ASP.NET Core on linux with intermediate certificates

Tags: asp.net-core, ssl

I'm writing an application using ASP.NET Core 6 that will run on linux.

The certificate we have is signed using an intermediate certificate.

When I configure an application in linux to use this certificate, I need to specify cert-file, key-file and CA file (bundle file of the intermediate certificate).

In ASP.NET Core there does not seem to be any way to specify the CA file.

On Windows I can use this certificate with the Asp.net app because the intermediate certificate is installed in the certificate store...

How can I use this certificate when running the asp.net app on linux?

Thanks,
Nadav

Comment: **Typo** alert: it's **intermediate** - not "intermidiate" ....

Answer (score 0):

I have researched the related tutorials about adding https in asp.net core application[Linux].

Let me summarize it, first , [we need to trust the certificate](https://andrewlock.net/creating-and-trusting-a-self-signed-certificate-on-linux-for-use-in-kestrel-and-asp-net-core/). Something like

```
#Install the cert utils
sudo apt install libnss3-tools
# Trust the certificate for SSL 
pk12util -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -i localhost.pfx
# Trust a self-signed server certificate
certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -A -t "P,," -n 'dev cert' -i localhost.crt
```

Then we can configure it

```
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
{
    serverOptions.ConfigureEndpointDefaults(listenOptions =>
    {
        listenOptions.UseHttps("localhost.pfx", "testpassword");
    });
});
```